# apt pinning several packages in one section

Tags: apt

Say I have a section in /etc/apt/preferences:

```
Package: m4
Pin: release a=lenny-backports
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

How do I add several packages more instead of copying a section again and specifying a list of packages? I have not found the way to do it and grouping like * (all packages) or a single name is either too wide or too narrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use glob to pin several packages:

All packages that contains `gnome`:

```
Package: /gnome/
Pin: release a=lenny-backports
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

All packages that contains `gnome` or the package called `kde`:

```
Package: /gnome/ kde
Pin: release a=lenny-backports
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

All packages that contains `gnome` or `gdm`:

```
Package: /(gnome|gdm)/
Pin: release a=lenny-backports
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

All packages starting with `m4`:

```
Package: m4*
Pin: release a=lenny-backports
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

All packages ending with `m4`:

```
Package: *m4
Pin: release a=lenny-backports
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

You can learn more about glob using `man 7 glob`.